# What should I add to no javascript file to create an executable in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, unix, executable

I'm trying to create an executable in the Ubuntu console, but I do not get it.

The truth is that I have only tried with the following command, put by more than I search in google, I can not find anything. Look for possible questions in Stack Overflow, but none of them convinced me.

This is what I add at the beginning of my file, without success:

```
#! / bin / node
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only substitute what you use for the next line and it will work perfectly for you.

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
```